# Accessing Docker container from another machine in an internal network

Tags: c#, linux, docker, networking, asp.net-core

I'm attempting to run a asp.net core application from a raspberry pi using docker, I think I have the main parts down. I have a repository on github that is a simplistic asp.net core project. I have setup an account on docker cloud which build everytime I push to my github repo.

I have docker pulled my repository onto my pi:
[image: screenshot of docker image being on pi]

I run the command:
`docker run -d -p 8080:80 joro550/radiusnet --network=host`
and I can see that it is running:
[image: image of docker image running]

But when I go to my pi's ip address on port 8080 then I get this:
[image: Connection refused screen shot]

When I've been searching around for this people have suggested adding these flags (which I have tried and come up with the same results:

- adding --network=host to the docker run command
- adding -it to the docker run command
- Adding Expose 80 into the docker file

I think at this point I'm at a bit of a lose as to how to access this thing.
The docker documentation does suggest running

```
`docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" myapp`
```

If I'm using windows 10 Nano containers, which I don't believe I'm using but when I run this command I get a resounding `<no value>`

Cutting it back to `docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" myapp` gives me a different ip address to my ips internal ip address, which I've tried on port 8080 and get the same result

Doing a curl on both addresses gives me the same result of connection refused:
[image: curl failing on ip address]

Here's my docker file for anyone interested:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY /src ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out -r linux-arm

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.0-runtime-stretch-arm32v7
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/src/RadiusNet.Web/out .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RadiusNet.Web.dll"]
```

If any more information is needed please ask, I'm pretty new to Docker so I just did a bit of a knowledge dump of my current situation.

Link to github project (if it's needed): https://github.com/joro550/RadiusNet

Any help - at this point will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the IP you are using to connect to the container? Make sure it is the container IP as docker is kind of problematic in Windows and unable to connect using "http://localhost:port" 

Additionally, you might need to add firewall rules on the nanoserver to allow connections to port 5000

Comment: The docker container is running in Linux on the pi rather than on my windows machine, I'm simply using the Windows machine to attempt to connect to it, all though the firewall rules might not be a bad place to start

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

> Cutting it back to docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" myapp gives me a different ip address to my ips internal ip address, which I've tried on port 8080 and get the same result

Try curling the port 5000 and 80 with this IP address from inside the raspbery pi rather than 8080. Plus, are you sure you are exposing the right port? You have "expose 80" but the port 8080 is mapped to 5000, and docker ps shows no mapping for 80

Comment: Curling with port 5000 is still giving me the same result, would you suggest changing my docker run parameters? I'm just pushing a new docker file exposing port 5000

Comment: It is weird tho, because you are running with "-p 8080:80" but you can see in docker ps, 8080 is bound to 5000. If this is a firewall issue, 80 is more likely to be open by default as it is the default web port. But yeah, if 8080 is always directed to there no matter your parameters (why tho?) exposing 5000 might work.

try this: 
docker network inspect <networkname> 
See if your containers are attached. If they are, try finding out the container IP, and curl to that IP from within the raspberry pi. Maybe your filter just does not return the right IP address